# Addthis widget and twitter

Tags: addthis

I use addthis widget.
When I share on Twitter, it says this: http://mysite.com/brands/elkay.html#.UC5Pv4VlFNU.twitter 
What is ".UC5Pv4VlFNU.twitter" - how to remove this suffix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:
need to add

```
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":false, "data_track_clickback":false}</script>
```

before addthis js file